# Apply HTML Base URL To Images Only Not Href

Tags: html, svn, prefix

I have svn setup and wamp installed on my local machine. Im going to use this to test and then commit. My issue is that the /images directory is 25gb. I didnt add this directory to SVN and i dont want to have to keep this directory up to date all the time. 
Is it possible to apply html base just to images.

```
   <base href="http://website.net">
```

This way i can use the images from the live server, but clicking links and stuff wont redirect me to the live site.

I have code set up to determine whether it is being run on the live machine or test so it is possible for me to add some badly written code so long as it does the job as it wont effect the live machine.

Comment: I am also having the same issue :(

Comment: I had to use jquery to get around this. Its slow but it works for a test machine. If test machine dont output base url. Use jquery to append base url to all images